# Decode the message $(1,1,1,0,1,1,1)$ using the Hamming $ (7,4)$ code

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

The question is asking me to decode $(1,1,1,0,1,1,1)$ using Hamming $(7,4)$ code. I know that I am suppose to set a $3 \times 7$ matrix ${\bf H}$ and multiply it by ${\bf r}$ and set it equal to zero, but I am confused to how I determine what the values for ${\bf H}$ are.

Answer (score 1):

The parity-check matrix of the mentioned code is:
$${\bf H} =\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&1
\end{array}\right).$$
Now if you multiply your received vector ${\bf r} = (1,~1,~1,~0,~1,~1,~1)$ by ${\bf H}$, you get:
$${\bf H}{\bf r}^T = (4,~4,~3)^T$$
that is equal to $(0,~0,~1)^T$ modulo two (binary operations). This column corresponds to the $4$th column oh ${\bf H}$, which implies that there has been an error on that position. Hence the sent codeword was ${\bf c} = (1,~1,~1,~1,~1,~1,~1)$. This can be verified to be codeword by checking if ${\bf H}{\bf c}^T$ equals zero modulo two or not.

Comment: How do I obtain the parity-check matrix?

Comment: The parity check matrix of a Hamming code $[n,k,d_\min] = [2^m-1,2^m-1-m,m]$ can be constructed by listing all binary columns of length $m$, which are pair-wise independent. Note that the order of this listing does not matter.

Comment: @Luckyluck63 - I am not getting how $H$ is a parity check matrix. Shouldn't there be a $3 \times 3 $ identity matrix augmented in $H$ ?

Comment: @Dark_Knight You can change the order of the columns of the ${\bf H}$ and (1) get identity matrix in the left block of ${\bf H}$ and (2) the decoding process continues the same. Let's suppose we have exchanged the third and forth columns of the above ${\bf H}$ to get a new one, which by abuse of notation, we still show by ${\bf H}$. In that case, ${\bf H}{\bf r}^T = (3,~3,~4)^T = (1,~1,~0)^T \pmod{2}$, that is again the forth column of the new ${\bf H}$. Hence, the sent codeword is again the all-one codeword.